# Python university task

Tags: python, task

Task conditions:

The payroll is presented as two tables. First contains
the names of the employees of the shop, and the second - their salary for the current month. Find a last name an employee whose salary is the least deviated from the average salary of all
employees for the current month. Find the names of the two workers with the largest
salaries. Remove employee information from payroll, whose salary is minimal.

I wrote such code to find a last name an employee whose salary is the least deviated from the average salary:

```
N = int(input('Enter number of workers: '))
salaries_arr = []
surnames_arr = []
for i in range(N):
    print('Worker', i + 1)
    surnames = input(f'Enter surname of worker {i + 1}: ', )
    salary = int(input(f'Salary of worker {i + 1}: '))
    salaries_arr.append(salary)
    surnames_arr.append(surnames)
info_arr = list(zip(surnames_arr, salaries_arr))
average_salary = sum(salaries_arr) / N
print(info_arr)
print(average_salary)
difference_salary = []
for i in range(N):
    difference_salary.append(abs(salaries_arr[i] - average_salary))
print(difference_salary)
minima = max(difference_salary)
pos = 0
for j in range(N):
    if difference_salary[j] < minima:
        minima = difference_salary[j]
        pos = j
print("Minimal salary deviation has worker: ", surnames_arr[pos])
```

But i can't understand how can I find the other two conditions. I will be grateful for your ideas or solutions.

Comment: To find the two largest salaries. Iterate over the list and keep track of the highest value. Next, iterate over the list again and keep track of the highest value that is lower than the highest value you just found. To find the minimal salary, increment over the list and keep track of the smallest value. I would think the question you completed is the hardest of the three.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- To know the names of the two workers with the largest salaries, You can do following steps -

  1. Sort the `info_arr` array in decreasing order on the basis of salary.
  2. The first two elements of the sorted array will have the name of two workers with largest salaries.
     In code it will be like this

```py
sorted_salary = sorted(info_arr, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
largest_salary_person1 = sorted_salary[0]
largest_salary_person2 = sorted_salary[1]
```

- To Remove employee information from payroll, whose salary is minimal do following steps -

  1. Loop through the salary of all employees and store index of employee having least salary.
  2. Pop element at above calculated index from both `salaries_arr` and `surname_arr`.

```py
    # Find worker having least salary
    least_salary_worker_index = 0
    least_salary = salary_arr[0]
    for i in range(1, len(salary_arr)):
        current_worker_salary = salary_arr[i]
        if current_worker_salary < least_salary:
            least_salary = current_worker_salary
            least_salary_worker_index = i

    # Remove information of employee with least salary
    salary_arr.pop(least_salary_worker_index)
    surname_arr.pop(least_salary_worker_index)
```

Comment: You would need to combine the surnames and salary lists before sorting by salary, because the index of the salary would not reference the same index of the surname after sorting.

Comment: @Sri Thanks for pointing out the mistake. Updated code to sort the combined list.

Comment: Thanks for your solution! It's looking more easy that I thought a couple of hours ago.  :)